# How to declare a variable for only using in template in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have below code

```
  <ion-card >
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-chip *ngFor="let skill of contact.skills | split">
        <ion-label>{{skill}}</ion-label>
      </ion-chip>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

then I want to hide the card if there is no skills, so I changed it to

```
  <ion-card [hidden]="(contact.skills | split).length == 0">
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-chip *ngFor="let skill of contact.skills | split">
        <ion-label>{{skill}}</ion-label>
      </ion-chip>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

and it's working fine, but the problem is value is going to split pipe twice, then how can I define a variable and using pipe once?

I tried below but not working

```
  <ion-card #skills="contact.skills | split" [hidden]="skills.length == 0">
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-chip *ngFor="let skill of skills">
        <ion-label>{{skill}}</ion-label>
      </ion-chip>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use template variables to assign custom values.

Template variables can only be used to refer to elements and components directly or by name (`exportAs`) or to assign values from a structural directives context like `let idx=index` in `*ngFor`

For your use case create a field in the components class instead and bind to this class.